# Proof of hall's marriage theorem by Halmos

Tags: graph-theory

This is one of the various proofs for Hall's theorem.
[image]

I have a question in Case 2 explanation. Let T $\subseteq$S. 
Then how can we conclude $N_{G}(S\cup T)$ $\subseteq$ $N_{G}(S)$$\cup$ $N_{Q}(T)$
What I dont understand is that some of the vertices in T can have corresponding vertices in N(S) and not necessarily only in Q.

Comment: Note that in the case you speak of they used T again to describe **$T \subseteq X-S$**.

Comment: Studentmath is correct. They assume $T \subseteq X - S$. Vertices in $X-S$ can have neighbors in $P$ or in $Q$.

Comment: Okay. But how to conclude that $N_{G}(S\cup T)$ $\subseteq$ $N_{G}(S)$$\cup$ $N_{Q}(T)$

Comment: And also $N_{G}(T)$ can have elements both from $P$ and $Q$ so how does the inequality hold ?